# How do I create a certain ratio of row heights in a PySimpleGUI element?

Tags: tkinter, tk-toolkit, pysimplegui

I am using PySimpleGUI to create the front-end for an application.

As part of the interface, I have a two elements arranged vertically on a Tab element: a Table and a Canvas.

I would like both elements to fill the entire space horizontally, but I would like to have the Table occupy 2/3 of the space vertically and the Canvas to occupy the other 1/3. I have tried various ways to expand and size the elements, but they both inevitably occupy half of the vertical space each.

I am developing the application on Windows and I believe that the underlying toolkit is TK, so perhaps there is a lower-level approach that could work.

Thank you for your ideas and suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Refer [Tkinter Pack() setting a ratio for expanding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61283452/tkinter-pack-setting-a-ratio-for-expanding)

It cannot be done under PySimpleGUI which is built by `pack` method.

Here's the hack way to change geometry manager from `pack` to `grid` under PySimpleGUI, but visible/invisible options will not work anymore.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

headings = ['President', 'Date of Birth']
data = [
    ['Ronald Reagan', 'February 6'],
    ['Abraham Lincoln', 'February 12'],
    ['George Washington', 'February 22'],
    ['Andrew Jackson', 'March 15'],
    ['Thomas Jefferson', 'April 13'],
    ['Harry Truman', 'May 8'],
    ['John F. Kennedy', 'May 29'],
    ['George H. W. Bush', 'June 12'],
    ['George W. Bush', 'July 6'],
    ['John Quincy Adams', 'July 11'],
    ['Garrett Walker', 'July 18'],
    ['Bill Clinton', 'August 19'],
    ['Jimmy Carter', 'October 1'],
    ['John Adams', 'October 30'],
    ['Theodore Roosevelt', 'October 27'],
    ['Frank Underwood', 'November 5'],
    ['Woodrow Wilson', 'December 28'],
]

size = (480, 320)

font = ('Courier New', 11)
sg.theme('DarkBlue3')
sg.set_options(font=font)

layout = [
    [sg.Table(data, headings=headings, justification='left', expand_x=True, expand_y=True, key='-TABLE-')],
    [sg.Graph(size, (0, 0), size, background_color='green', expand_x=True, expand_y=True, key='-GRAPH-')],
]

window = sg.Window('Title', layout, resizable=True, finalize=True)
height = window['-TABLE-'].Widget.winfo_reqheight()//2
window['-GRAPH-'].Widget.configure(height=height)
width = window['-GRAPH-'].CanvasSize[0]
window['-GRAPH-'].CanvasSize = (width, height)
table = window['-TABLE-'].Widget.master.master
table.pack_forget()
graph = window['-GRAPH-'].Widget.master
graph.pack_forget()
table.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=sg.tk.NSEW)
graph.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=sg.tk.NSEW)
root = table.master
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=2)
root.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
# Size of Graph changed, maybe you need to update following arguments
# window['-GRAPH-'].change_coordinates(graph_bottom_left, graph_top_right)
window.read(close=True)
```

If window not resizable, it will be much easier, just use following code from statement `window = sg.Window(...)`

```py
window = sg.Window('Title', layout, finalize=True)
height = window['-TABLE-'].Widget.winfo_reqheight()//2
window['-GRAPH-'].Widget.configure(height=height)
width = window['-GRAPH-'].CanvasSize[0]
window['-GRAPH-'].CanvasSize = (width, height)
# Size of Graph changed, maybe you need to update following arguments
# window['-GRAPH-'].change_coordinates(graph_bottom_left, graph_top_right)
window.read(close=True)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the response! Unfortunately, in explaining the issue, I neglected to mention that my Tab element, as part of a TabGroup, is part of a Column element. I think this is leading to an error when using your proposed solution: "_tkinter.TclError: cannot use geometry manager grid inside .!toplevel.!frame3.!panedwindow.!frame2.!frame2.!notebook.!frame2 which already has slaves managed by pack". Is there a workaround?

Comment: Here all widgets under widget.master should use same geometry manager.  Find out same master widget, then `pack_forget` all the child widgets then `grid` them back. For example, `table` is `.!toplevel.!frame` and `graph` is `.!toplevel.!frame2`, they have same master or parent, `.!toplevel`, and it have only two child widgets `.!toplevel.!frame` and `.!toplevel.!frame2`, so `pack_foget` all of them, and then `grid` all of them back. Any widget still packed, you cannot grid others.

Comment: Update if window not resizable.

Comment: Thank you! I'll give that a try.